# Filter HashMap with Morphia

Tags: mongodb, hashmap, morphia

My entity contains this field :

```
@Embedded
public Map<String, Integer> map;
```

In a query I want to filter against this map, all the elements must have the same key/value of the Map passed in parameter.

I tried this as suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/morphia/STfIoBSvt9I) :

```
for (Entry<String, Integer> e : myMap.entrySet()) {
    query.filter("map." + e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}
```

It's working but I have warnings and I don't like it :

```
[warn] o.m.m.q.QueryValidator - The type(s) for the query/update may be inconsistent; using an instance of type 'java.lang.Integer' for the field 'models.MyModel.map' which is declared as 'java.util.Map'
[warn] o.m.m.q.QueryValidator - Validation warnings: 
[Validation failed: 'Type java.util.Map may not be queryable with value '2' with class java.lang.Integer']
```

So I'm looking for another way to do this. I tried all of these and none is working :

```
query.field("map").equal(myMap);
query.filter("map", myMap);
query.field("map").hasAllOf(myMap.entrySet());
query.field("map").hasAllOf(myMap.keySet());
```

Is it a problem of Map ordering or something else ? Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: "None is working" means that you don't get the desired result or that you're always getting the warning?

Comment: Sorry, you're right I was not clear. It means that I don't have the expected result but no warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in morphia: https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/641. You need to disable validation on the Query instance: `query.disableValidation();`

Their analysis is: "It sounds incorrect, although the query validation failures should just be in the log, not throwing an exception, so this shouldn't be a show-stopper." And as of the time of my answer, they've marked it for resolution in the "post-1.0" milestone.